# Connent to website with proxy not working (python)

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, proxies

Im trying to connect to a website with a proxy, but it keeps connecting with my ip.

```
import requests
proxies = {
    "https": "103.224.5.5:54143"
}
url = 'http://httpbin.org/ip'
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
ciao=r.json()
print(ciao)
```